# Functions failing to toggle and perform their actions

Tags: java

This is the build for an autoclicker I've been making, everything works the UI opens and everything but the actual function of being able to toggle it on and off and also use the autoclicker and other functions don't work.

I'm not sure what the error actually is or where it's even happening, these are the errors I'm getting in Console.

```
Jun 06, 2017 4:54:42 AM java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary load
INFO: hook_get_auto_repeat_rate [42]: SPI_GETKEYBOARDSPEED: 31.

Jun 06, 2017 4:54:42 AM java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary load
INFO: hook_get_auto_repeat_delay [56]: SPI_GETKEYBOARDDELAY: 1.

Jun 06, 2017 4:54:42 AM java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary load
INFO: hook_get_pointer_acceleration_multiplier [70]: SPI_GETMOUSE[2]: 1.

Jun 06, 2017 4:54:42 AM java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary load
INFO: hook_get_pointer_acceleration_threshold [84]: SPI_GETMOUSE[0]: 6.

Jun 06, 2017 4:54:42 AM java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary load
INFO: hook_get_pointer_acceleration_threshold [86]: SPI_GETMOUSE[1]: 10.

Jun 06, 2017 4:54:42 AM java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary load
INFO: hook_get_pointer_sensitivity [101]: SPI_GETMOUSESPEED: 10.

Jun 06, 2017 4:54:42 AM java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary load
INFO: hook_get_multi_click_time [115]: GetDoubleClickTime: 500.
```

I'm not sure where these are occuring nor what they really mean to be honest, I think they're occuring in my listeners for Keyboard and Mouse movements however I'm not positive.

If someone could point me in the right direction of debugging this as these are the only errors I get when I attempt to in console and it shows no real help on how to fix these issues.

Comment: Those look like logging statements not errors are you sure that they are the result of errors?

Comment: "INFO" is not "ERROR" or "WARNING". "INFO" is just info. Based on these non-errors, I doubt anyone can tell you if there's something wrong with your code, never mind how to fix it. If your code is not working as you desire, you should post a [mcve].